Why my join query in SQLAlchemy won't work with 4 filters
I am building a birthday reminder app and am working on the notifications bell in flask. When I open up the notifications it should populate with the user birthdays that the user follows that are coming up in less than one month and/or are today. Doesn't work even though there are clearly birthdays in the database within the right date and timeframe.
@app.context_processor
def base():
    def notifbday():
        if current_user.is_authenticated:
            user_id = flask_login.current_user.id
            # Get the current date
            today = datetime.now()
            # Calculate the date one month earlier
            one_month_later = today + relativedelta(months=1)
            print(one_month_later)

            currentyear = func.extract('year', today)

            birthdays_in_last_month = User.query.join(
                Follow, User.id == Follow.follower_id
            ).filter(
                    func.extract('month', User.birthday) <= one_month_later.month,
                    func.extract('day', User.birthday) <= one_month_later.day,
                    func.extract('month', User.birthday) >= today.month,
                    func.extract('day', User.birthday) >= today.day
            ).all()

            print(birthdays_in_last_month)
            
            return birthdays_in_last_month

    return dict(notif=notifbday)

It did work when I did like this only but stopped after adding all four filters.
birthdays_in_last_month = User.query.join(
                Follow, User.id == Follow.follower_id
            ).filter(
                    func.extract('month', User.birthday) >= today.month,
                    func.extract('day', User.birthday) >= today.day
            ).all()

<div class="popup" id="myPopup">
        <i id="notif" class="fa fa-bell" style="font-size: 48px; color: red"></i>
        <div id="popuptext">
          {% if notif() != None %} {% for n in notif() %}
          <div class="notifmsgs">
            <p>
              {{ n.username }}'s birthday is coming up on {{ n.birthday.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') }}
            </p>

          </div>
          {% endfor %}{% endif %}

        </div>
      </div>


Have you tried using between in your filter? .filter(User.birthday.between(today, one_month_later))

I just tried that but the thing is it needs to be filtered using only the month and day and that still made it show up with nothing. I tried to print the query filter but nothing would print in the python terminal.

The User query join was reversed. Had to change to User.id == Follow.followed_id not follower_id
@app.context_processor
def base():
    def notifbday():
        print('test')
        if current_user.is_authenticated:
            print('test')
            user_id = flask_login.current_user.id
            # Get the current date
            today = datetime.now()
            # Calculate the date one month earlier
            one_month_later = today + relativedelta(months=1)
            print(one_month_later)
            one_month_before = today - relativedelta(months=12)

            birthdays_in_last_month = User.query.join(
                Follow, User.id == Follow.followed_id
            ).filter(
                (func.extract('month', User.birthday) >= today.month),
            (func.extract('month', User.birthday) <= one_month_later.month)).all()

            print(birthdays_in_last_month)
            
            return birthdays_in_last_month
        else:
            print('user is not logged in')

    return dict(notif=notifbday)

